# Android Create Corner swipe Menu Like Omni Swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

I want to create Corner swipe menu like Omni Swipe

[image: Omni Swipe]

or Android Pie Control (http://www.apkthing.com/tools/10052-pie-control.html)

I tried the sample here but not suitable for my requirement: https://github.com/sephiroth74/OverlayMenu

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using **CircularFloatingActionMenu :**
[image]

**Link :** https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu

Further you can add android BoomMenu to it :
[image]

**Link :** 
https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu

Comment: Thanks @Amit I need an overlay menu with swipe not floating action menu